# How to select distinct combinations of 2 rows in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

How do I select the distinct combinations of 2 rows.

eg. given the following table

```
Col1 Col2
A     B
A     B
A     C
C     B
B     A
```

I want to select

```
Col1 Col2
A      B
A      C
C      B
```

Note that just using the distinct key word will not work as it will include the last row B,A.

I don't want the last row to be returned because the reverse combination (A,B) is already in the set.

Comment: If you have A, B and B, A, which one do you want to see?

Comment: I've got a feeling this is a confusion between a set of data which SQL is optimised for, and a Mathematical Set where two sets can be equal if they contain the same items, regardless of the order.

Comment: @Brandon, to be honest I don't care, as long as one and only one of them appears.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t1.col1,t1.col2 FROM table t1 WHERE col2 not in (SELECT t2.col1 FROM table t2 WHERE t2.col2 = t1.col1) GROUP BY t1.col1,t1.col2
```

or

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.col1, t1.col2 FROM table t1 WHERE col2 not in (SELECT t2.col1 FROM table t2 WHERE t2.col2 = t1.col1)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is interesting to note that none of the above solutions provide a correct answer to the problem.

Herewith two possible answers that can be used:

Firstly to generate the "BASE Table" (Note: I've added a few extra test cases):

```
Declare @Test table (Column1 varchar(10), Column2 varchar(10))

Insert into @Test
VALUES ('A','B'),('A','B'),('A','C'),('C','B'),('B','A'),('D', 'A'), ('d','e'), ('a', 'b'), ('C','A')

select *  from @Test
```

This results in:

```
Column1     Column2
A           B
A           B
A           C
C           B
B           A
D           A
d           e
a           b
C           A
```

Now for the queries:

**Query Option 1:**

```
;WITH numb as ( Select *, Num = ROW_NUMBER() Over(Order by Column1,Column2) from @Test)
, Num2 as ( Select T.*, n.Num from @Test t
        Inner Join numb n on (t.Column1 = n.Column1 and t.Column2 = n.Column2) or (t.Column1 = n.Column2 and t.Column2 = n.Column1))
,rankk as ( select *, rnk = rank() Over(partition by num order by Column1)  from Num2)

select DISTINCT Column1, Column2 from rankk where rnk = 1
```

**Results Option 1:**

```
Column1     Column2
a           b
A           C
C           B
D           A
d           e
```

**Query Option 2:**

```
;WITH source AS ( SELECT Column1, Column2, 
      Test = (CASE WHEN Column1 < Column2 THEN Column1 ELSE Column2 END
             + CASE WHEN Column1 > Column2 THEN Column1 ELSE Column2 END)  
      FROM (
            SELECT Distinct Column1, Column2
            FROM @Test AS bd
      ) AS sub1
)
SELECT Column1 =  MIN(s.Column1), Column2 =  MAX(s.Column2)
FROM source AS s
GROUP BY s.Test;
```

**Results Option 2:**

```
Column1     Column2
A           B
A           C
D           A
C           B
d           e
```

**Note:** the results of the 2 queries are slightly different, but both queries return **the same and correct result set**.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this with SQL; Whilst SQL is optimised for dealing with Sets of data, this is not the same as mathematical set where by regardless of order, a set equals another set because it contains the same items.

I would implement or use a proper Set class in your program that does understand the mathematical set logic, and that could be used to then exclude results from the SQL query.

Comment: Just to clarify; yes you *can* obviously do this in SQL; I don't believe you *should* do this in SQL though.

Answer (score 0):

I verified the below works.  If you want to make it work against more sets, then you would include additional NOT EXISTS statement combinations.

```
WITH BaseData
AS
    (SELECT Column1, Column2
    FROM (VALUES
        ('A', 'B'), ('A', 'B'), ('A', 'C'), ('C', 'B'), ('B', 'A')) val (Column1, Column2))
SELECT Column1, Column2
FROM
    (SELECT Column1, Column2
    FROM BaseData
    GROUP BY Column1, Column2) sub1
WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT 1
    FROM BaseData
    WHERE Column1 = Column2
    AND Column2 = Column1);
```